# How to change self in NSDate extension Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, swift-extensions

I am trying to write an extension where NSDate can be changed to the another date. I want to make an extension which will modify self.

I've check different methods but cannot find how to modify self
I am trying something like that but it doesn't work.

```
extension NSDate {
    func changeDate(unitType: NSCalendarUnit, number: Int, date: NSDate) {

        self.laterDate(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
            .Day,
            value: number,
            toDate: date,
            options: []
        )!)
    }
}
```

In another file I am doing something like that:

```
let date = NSDate()
// set date to tomorrow
date.changeDate(.Day, number: 1, date: date)
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`NSDate` reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/) (emphasis added):

> Date objects are **immutable,** ...

and therefore you cannot mutate `self` in an extension method. You'll have
to return the new date as another `NSDate` object, e.g.

```
extension NSDate {

    func changedDate(unitType: NSCalendarUnit, number: Int) -> NSDate {
        return self.laterDate(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
            .Day,
            value: number,
            toDate: self,
            options: []
            )!)
    }
}

var date = NSDate()
date = date.changedDate(.Day, number: 1)
```